# Using expect for authentication

Tags: pi-3b+

I have installed the **Nordvpn linux app**
After using it for some days I have realised I need to login again sometimes.

Login is done by the command and the response is:

```
root@root:~ $ nordvpn login
Please enter your login details.
Email / Username:        
Password:
```

I want to automate this login using a **login.sh script**. I tried using this:

```
#!/bin/bash
nordvpn login
expect "Email / Username: "
send "example@gmail.com"
expect "Password: "
send "password"
```

I'm getting this **output**:

```
couldn't read file "Email / Username: ": no such file or directory
login.sh: 4: login.sh: send: not found
couldn't read file "Password: ": no such file or directory
login.sh: 6: login.sh: send: not found
```

**Update: Changed my login.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn nordvpn login
expect "Email / Username: "
send "example.com\r"
"Password: "
send "password\r"
expect eof
```

It worked for the first time. I tried logging out and again to login getting this output:

```
spawn nordvpn login
You are already logged in.
send: spawn id exp4 not open
  while executing
```

But I am not logged in

Comment: If you are using expect, shouldn't your 1st line be, "#!/usr/bin/expect"? Or wherever your expect is?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, although I had some issues with sending the password this way.

```
#!/bin/bash
expect <<END
            spawn nordvpn connect $parameter_country  
            expect "Email / Username"
            send "user_name_here\r"
            expect "Password"
            send "password_here"
            send "\r"
            expect eof
END
```